# Axioms of Newtonian Mechanics

Tags: reference-request, axioms, classical-mechanics, formal-proofs

Axiomatically speaking, could Newton's laws be derived (as theorems) from the conservation of momentum and energy -- along with a few suitable definitions of things like an inertia frame and force?  Is there a book which takes this axiomatic viewpoint?

Comment: Something like [Lagrangian mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics)?

Comment: Lagrangian mechanics is based on the principle of least action (somthing I've always thought very unintuitive) -- not the conservation of momentum and energy.

Comment: Have you looked at [C.J. Papachristou's approach](http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.2326)?  He derives Newton's laws from just the principle of superposition, the conservation of linear momentum, and several definitions.

Comment: Thanks Bye_World.  That's what I was looking for.  Do you know of a book which uses that approach?

Comment: @user234659 I do not.

Comment: In [Papachristou](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1205/1205.2326.pdf) together with the additiveness of forces he states only one postulate (the conservation of linear momentum) so it is missing a postulate equivalent to the conservation of kinetic energy which is necessary to obtain an unique solution for the collision of two balls.